# river configuration for shard mongdb enviroinment

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch

How to configure shard "mongodb" environment to ES using river plugin?
I found how to setup river "mongodb" for replica "mongodb".but i  cant find any guide or reference to set up "river-mongodb" for shared "mongodb" enviroinment.

Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: I am not very familiar with river plugin. If the plugin is using oplog tailing based approach, it may have issues in sharded environment until it goes to each shard. An alternative is a generic mongo-connector (https://github.com/10gen-labs/mongo-connector) that an be used to connect mongodb data content to various systems like solr etc

Comment: Thsnks for your comments.. i ll look at it..!